# Update from stored procedure return

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure that I want to run on every row in a table that matches a where clause, the procedure already exists on the server and is used in other places so it cannot be modified for these changes.

The stored procedure returns a scalar value, I need to store this value in a column in the table, I've tried using the update:

```
UPDATE tbl SET tbl.Quantity = 
EXEC checkQuantity @ProductID = tbl.ProductID, @Quantity = tbl.Quantity
FROM orders tbl WHERE orderNumber = @orderNumber
```

But this of course doesn't work, is there a way to do this without multiple queries, reading the line info, running the proc in a loop then updating the original line?

Comment: I do have all the required info in my application's backend at this point already, I was hoping to be able to do this without looping through and sending two queries (one to run the proc, one to update the row) per line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no way to do this without multiple queries.   This is one of the few scenarios where a cursor or loop is necessary.

Unless you can replace your stored procedure with a user-defined function, which can be run in the context of a single query.

Comment: Not possible, the proc has code that cannot be used inside a function.

Comment: Is it possible to wrap the call to the stored procedure in a function call? Then he could call such function and assign the result to tbl.Quantity. Never tried it, but it could work

Comment: @Andrew Ok then, no function. Just out of curiosity, which kind of code is the one preventing that function execution?

Comment: The actual proc includes inserts, updates and dynamic sql

Comment: @Andrew, change it to make your SP support set-based computations then. For now it can handle only single `ProductID` at a time - change this.